# "perlsupport is not recognized." when installing perlsupport on vim

Tags: linux, perl, vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to use [perl-support.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=556). I followed the instructions:

1. I downloaded the zip file and copied it in ~HOME/.vim
2. I unzipped it there and opening vim and typing `:help perlsupport` I have an error: perlsupport is not recognized.
3. Typing `:scriptnames` I don't see it as part of the loaded plugins.

I then noticed that in ~/HOME/.vim once I unzip it created some directories inside `.vim` and not in `.vim/perl-support` like e. G ftplugin, etc. I deleted everything related to this plugin and I created a directory named `perl-support` under $HOME/.vim and then inside $HOME/.vim/perl-support I run `unzip perl-support.zip`.

I tried again the `:help perlsupport` but no success. What am I messing up here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin should be installed so that it looks like this when inside `~/.vim` (Generated by `tree`)

```
~/.vim
├── README
├── autoload
│   ├── mmtemplates
│   │   └── core.vim
│   ├── mmtoolbox
│   │   ├── make.vim
│   │   └── tools.vim
│   ├── perlsupportprofiling.vim
│   └── perlsupportregex.vim
├── doc
│   ├── ChangeLog
│   ├── perl-hot-keys.pdf
│   ├── perl-hot-keys.tex
│   ├── perlsupport.txt
│   ├── pmdesc3.text
│   ├── templatesupport.txt
│   ├── toolbox.txt
│   └── toolboxmake.txt
├── ftplugin
│   ├── make.vim
│   ├── perl.vim
│   ├── pod.vim
│   └── qf.vim
├── perl-support
│   ├── README.perlsupport
│   ├── codesnippets
│   │   ├── RegularExpressions
│   │   │   ├── numeric-range-0-127
│   │   │   └── numeric-range-0-255
│   │   ├── SmallProf-variables.pl
│   │   ├── dot.SmallProf
│   │   ├── free-software-comment
│   │   ├── module-interface.pl
│   │   ├── new.pl
│   │   ├── pod-template-application.pl
│   │   ├── pod-template-module.pl
│   │   ├── print-data-structure-with-Dumper.pl
│   │   ├── print-hash-sorted.pl
│   │   ├── print-hash.pl
│   │   ├── process-all-files-in-a-directory-recursively.pl
│   │   └── slurp-file.pl
│   ├── modules
│   │   └── perl-modules.list
│   ├── rc
│   │   ├── customization.ctags
│   │   ├── customization.gvimrc
│   │   ├── customization.perltidyrc
│   │   ├── customization.smallprof
│   │   ├── customization.vimrc
│   │   └── sample_template_file
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── csv2err.pl
│   │   ├── pmdesc3.pl
│   │   └── wrapper.sh
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── Templates
│   │   ├── comments.templates
│   │   ├── filetests.templates
│   │   ├── idioms.templates
│   │   ├── pod.templates
│   │   ├── regex.templates
│   │   ├── snippets.templates
│   │   ├── specvar.templates
│   │   └── statements.templates
│   └── wordlists
│       └── perl.list
├── plugin
│   └── perl-support.vim
└── syntax
    └── template.vim
```

Then tun

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

This will generate the tags file so you have use the help documents.

---

It is most likely easier if you look at a vim plugin manager such as [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) or [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim).

Note: If you use pathogen you will need to run `:Helptags` before you can use help.

Comment: Interesting.Actually it was like that when I uninstalled it inside `$HOME/.vim` but it did not work. And I do have pathogen installed. But adding it in the `$HOME/.vim/bundle` folder and unzipping it there did not work either (meaning the `:help perlsupport` was rejected

Comment: @Jim the directory structure should be exactly the same as it above except the path should be something like `$HOME/.vim/bundle/perl-support.vim/`. Run `:Helptags` to make `:help perlsupport` work.

Comment: I unzipped in the bundle folder. I opened vim I typed `:Helptags` and then `:help perlsupport` and I got unrecognized option

Comment: @Jim you need to move it down one more directory. This might help explain things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366142/after-much-reading-i-still-cant-get-pathogen-to-load-a-plugin-under-windows/16366544#16366544. Its a slightly related question but it sort of explains the directory structure.

Comment: So create another directory inside bundle folder and unzip it there?

Comment: @Jim yes. Or run `cd ~/.vim/bundle && git clone https://github.com/vim-scripts/perl-support.vim`

Comment: +1 and accepted!But I can't undertand how this actually works.I can see the help but if I type `if{}` in insert mode it does not expand and I can not figure out from the help what I need to press

Comment: @Jim I have no idea how to use the plugin